# What is the quickest way to Determine if a ASP.NET project compiled with debug symbols?

Tags: asp.net

What is the quickest way to Determine if a ASP.NET project compiled with debug symbols?

Comment: Are there any .pdb files next to the application's dll?

Comment: you can have pdb files even in Release mode. Not the correct way to identify if it's debug or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only best way to do is check the compiled assemblies itself. There is this very useful tool called '.NET Assembly Information' found [here](http://www.codeplex.com/AssemblyInformation) by Rotem Bloom. After you install this it asociates .dll files to open with itself. After installing you can just double-click on the Assembly to open with it and it will give you the assembly details as displayed in the screenshop below. There you can identify if it's debug 
compiled or not.

[alt text http://ruchitsurati.net/myfiles/asm_info.jpg](http://ruchitsurati.net/myfiles/asm_info.jpg)

LinkText: http://www.codeplex.com/AssemblyInformation

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 2):

Look at the system.web/compilation node in the web.config. If it was compiled in debug mode, you'll see

```
<compilation debug="true">
```

For Web Application projects, you can also look for *.pdb files in the bin directory.

Comment: you can have a website compiled in Released mode ans still set the debug flag to true, Though not advisable. Assembly compilation and debug flag in web.config are not coupled with each other like this, though collectively they cause effect on application performance.